# Static website aliasing - doesn't work without www

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web, hosting

I set up a static website, with domain name bought from namecheap and hosted using AWS.

I tried following http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html but it's so hard to follow. My website only loads when I put "www" in front of my address. Can someone point me to a easy to follow tutorial or show me how I can correctly handle my aliasing?

Comment: You want the URL for your sign-in page to contain your company name (or other friendly identifier) instead of your AWS account ID? There's nothing to do with aws account aliases and your website URL.

Comment: Yeah I think you linked the wrong tutorial. Anyway, where are you hosting this static website, S3?

Comment: @MarkB yeah, my fault. I edited it. I'm hosting my website on S3

Comment: @RaviTezu I linked the wrong tutorial, I want my website to be reachable by simply typing example.com, instead of www.example.com. Right now if I don't add the www, I get a 404.

Answer (score 2):

Since the name of the S3 bucket has to match the name of the static website it is hosting you will need to create two S3 buckets named `domain.com` and `www.domain.com` where "domain.com" is you actual domain name. Configure records for both S3 buckets in Route53.

Next you need to pick which bucket you wish to be your default, and install your static website there. Then you need to setup a redirect rule in the other bucket to redirect to your default bucket. For example if you want the naked domain to be the default then you would setup a redirect rule in your "www" bucket to forward requests to the other bucket.